# can an Asp:Update Panel be Updated in a for loop, Simmilar To DoEvents() in windows forms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel

i have been trying to get an update panel to add controls to the screen as the code runs through a for look in the Back end C# code.

i have attempted this a lot of different ways, but no matter what i do i cant achieve this
is this possible to do using ASP.NET?

here is a simple example of what i mean.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID='mng' runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Add5" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers> 
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Place" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:Button ID="Add5" runat="server" Text="Add 5" OnClick="Add5_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

And the Code Behind

```
 protected void Add5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Place.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Test" + i + "<br />"));
            UPPnl.Update();                
        }
    }
```

I was hoping i would get a new line of text every time i debug through the Update method. but this does not seem to want to work

Any Idea's?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Have you checked that the Add5_Click method is being called?

Comment: I Don't Get any errors.
what happens is it runs through the for loop and only after it is complete it actually updates the screen.

I'm looking for a way to stop the loop, go and add an item to the screen. then carry on with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your Page_Load:

```
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Add5);
```

Comment: Thanks, Bit unfortunately that doesn't work ether. I'm thinking of just using SignalR. The only problem. my actual project is a lot more complex. so the implantation is not gonna be fun